# which are python best practices to concatenate different types of data?

Tags: python, concatenation

I want to generate bytes sequence containing string length and string content.
For example, for string `'hello'` I want to get `b'\x05hello'`
After some docs reading I've wrote a function:

```
def LenAndStrBytes(strdata):
  return bytearray([len(strdata)&0xFF])+strdata if strdata!=[] else 0
```

**question:**
I'm new in python programming and I wonder, which are best python practices to concatenate different types of data like `int` and something iterable like `bytearray`
Did I write my function optimally?

Comment: There is no "best practice" since you hardly ever need to do this, and when you do, it'll be to implement some file format or network protocol that lays down the appropriate constraints.

Comment: Stop trying to program C in Python. ;) Also, don't use the `backslash \\` syntax for line continuation - I didn't realise that was actually one line of code until I read it three times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just larsmans points out, it depends on your usage. If you can get the  result w/ clear code and fulfilling context limitation, it is nice practice which is suitable.

No need for `&0xFF`, bytearray checks to ensure values between 0 and 255.

```
>>> strdata = 'hello'
>>> bytearray([len(strdata)]) + strdata if strdata else bytearray()
bytearray(b'\x05hello')
```

And you could also

```
import struct
bytearray(struct.pack('B%ds' % len(strdata), len(strdata), strdata))
```

Comment: The `0xFF` is in fact dangerous because it gives the wrong result for `len(strdata)>255`, whereas your version will raise an exception. Note that `<` is not needed in `struct.pack` since bytes have no endianness.

Comment: @larsmans thanks, fixed the `<`. Yes, I intend to make it raise explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to serialise binary data before you write it to a file (or send it over a network?)

Did you perhaps mean to use the [`pickle` module](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) for data serialisation instead?